# I unwrapped the optional value but still getting this unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to IOS development and couldn't figure out how to resolve this error. Could any one help me out. Following is my code and the error point on the part of the code where I am using `NSNumberFormatter()`. waiting for your reply

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var display: UILabel!
    var usertyping
    = false

    @IBAction func appendDigit(sender: UIButton) {

        let digit = sender.currentTitle!
        if usertyping
        {
            display.text = display.text! + digit
        }
        else
        {
            display.text = digit
            usertyping = true
        }


    }

    @IBAction func operate(sender: UIButton) {

        let operation = sender.currentTitle!
        if usertyping{
            enter()
        }
        switch operation {
            case "×":
                if operandstack.count >= 2
                {
            displayValue = operandstack.removeLast() * operandstack.removeLast()
                    enter()
            }

        default: break

        }
    }
    var operandstack = Array<Double>()
    @IBAction func enter() {

        usertyping = false
        operandstack.append(displayValue)
        println("operandstack=\(operandstack)")

    }

    var displayValue: Double
        {
        get{

            return NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(display.text!)!.doubleValue

        }

        set{
            display.text="(\newValue)"
            usertyping=false
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it is failing over because `display.text` is nil or some invalid value.

Unwrapping an optional doesn't stop it being nil. It says that you realise that it could be nil, but you know that it isn't. If you are wrong and it is nil, it will fail.

Normally, unwrapping optionals for things like you are loading an image from a file. The file could be missing, but you know it isn't in your program, so you can assume the result can never be nil.

In your case, I assume `display.text` can be nil and you have to explicitly handle it or use optional chaining (the `?`).

Comment: You need to ask yourself what you want your program to do if the input is nil or invalid and then handle that. Maybe put in `if` in before you call the formatter.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 dangerous "!" in this line

```
return NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(display.text!)!.doubleValue
```

One on them could be the cause of your fatal error.

1. display.text! are you sure text is not nil?
2. numberFromString returns an optional, are you sure the input you are passing is something the method can transform into a NSNumber?

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is because `numberFromString` returns `nil` if there is no valid number found.

> An NSNumber object created by parsing string using the receiver’s
>   format. Returns nil if there are no numbers in the passed string.

Reference [numberFromString:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNumberFormatter/numberFromString:)

---

If your `display.text` doesn't have any valid number that statement will crash.

You can fix that by:

```
var displayValue: Double
{
    get
    {
        var returnVal = NSNumber(int: 0)
        if let dVal   = NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(display.text!)
        {
            returnVal = dVal
        }
        return returnVal.doubleValue
    }

    set
    {
        display.text = "(\newValue)"
        usertyping   = false
    }
}
```

Comment: it works but always return 0. i am confused why it is giving zero as display.text contains some value

Comment: @user2293224 Log the label value and let me know the result

Comment: I found that problem is in the "set" part of code. new value contains double value but some how "display.text = "\(newValue)" does not convert double into text. that is the problem